# Is it dangerous to use javascript:window.open in href tags?

Tags: xss, javascript

I have a website and would like to create a link to share information on a third-party site. Is it safe to use the `javascript:window.open()` function to do this? If unsafe, are there any ways this could be exploited by an attacker?

Sample code as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fshare.php%3Fu%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fmylink', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');void(0)" class="footer_link">
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/images/example.svg" alt="Share on Example" class="footer_icon"></a>
```

Comment: Unrelated: you have been a bit too generous on the URL-encoding. You should not URL-encode the full URL, only the relevant parameter. However, you should HTML-escape the `&` in the URL (`&amp;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination page can modify your page's DOM.

The *target* attribute defines where to open the destination page. If you open it in _blank, the destination page, which is in a new tab or window, will gain partial access to the parent linker. As a result, the destination page can overwrite the location the parent linker and can even execute a javascript.

It is called a **Reverse Tabnabbing**.

Comment: Could this only be exploited if the attacker had control of "www.example.com" ?

Comment: the only code on a blank page comes from the OP's server; no risk, unless OP has bigger problems.

Comment: @dandavis The arrival page can tab-nap OP's page. That is a **big** risk

Comment: Since the arrival page is on the HSTS preload list would this mitigate the issue? Also, would there be any way for an attacker to modify the arrival page and/or serve their own malicious site?